# Implementing Micro Manual LISP

Tags: lisp

I am implementing an interpreter for the LISP defined in,

http://www.scribd.com/vacuum?url=http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/pub/misc/micromanualLISP.pdf

My problem is the paper states that a LIST is,

```
4. (LIST e1 ... en) is defined for each n to be 
   (CONS e1 (CONS ... (CONS en NIL))).
```

So when a read in a list from the user such as,

```
(QUOTE (B C D (E F)))
```

using the above structure it becomes,

```
(QUOTE B C D E F)
```

There is no way to differentiate nested lists it all becomes a giant chain of cons.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(QUOTE (B C D (E F)))` is

```
(CONS B (CONS C (CONS D (CONS (CONS E (CONS F NIL)) NIL))))
```

`(QUOTE (B C D E F))` is

```
(CONS B (CONS C (CONS D (CONS E (CONS F NIL)) NIL)))
```

Or to put it another way:
`(LIST D (LIST E F))` = `(CONS D (CONS (LIST E F) NIL))`
`(LIST D E F)` = `(CONS D (LIST E F))`

Answer (score 2):

```
(QUOTE (B C D (E F)))
= (...  (CONS (E F) NIL))).
= (...  (CONS (CONS E (CONS F NIL)) NIL))).
```

which is different from

```
( ...(CONS D (CONS E (CONS F NIL))).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(QUOTE (B C D (E F))) = (LIST B C D (LIST E F))
```